# How to handle validation errors in Thymeleaf when the view is bound to a parameterised URL

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a form with a `date-time` input, like this:

```
<form th:object="${appointment}"
      method="post"
      th:action="@{/appointments/{id}/book (id=*{customerId})}">
    <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{dateTime}">
    <button type="submit">Book appointment</button>
</form>
```

The form is accessible via a URL like:
`http://localhost:8080/appointments/453ef24c-f11e-4f33-ae0a-d6cbde4c4d45/book`
Basically I need to pass the ID via the URL to create the appointment for the Customer with that ID.

I added a validation in the Model responsible to get the data from the form:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppointmentViewModel {
    @Future(message = "appointment date and time must not be in the past")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    private UUID customerId;
}
```

The validation is added because I want to display in Thymeleaf the validation error with something like:

```
<form th:object="${appointment}"
      method="post"
      th:action="@{/appointments/{id}/book (id=*{customerId})}">
    <input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{dateTime}">
    
    <!-- New code -->
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('dateTime')}" th:errors="*{dateTime}"></span>

    <button type="submit">Book appointment</button>
</form>
```

My controller would be something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class AppointmentsController {
    // ...

    @GetMapping("/{customerId}/book")
    String viewBookAppointment(@PathVariable("customerId") UUID customerId, Model model) {
        AppointmentViewModel appointmentViewModel = new AppointmentViewModel();
        appointmentViewModel.setCustomerId(customerId);
        // ...
        return "appointments/creation";
    }

    @PostMapping("/{customerId}/book")
    String bookAppointment(@PathVariable("customerId") UUID customerId,
                           @Valid AppointmentViewModel appointmentViewModel,
                           Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors())
            return "appointments/creation";

        // ...
    }
}
```

This way, I thought, I would be able to display the error in the view `appointments/creation`, but the solution above doesn't work because the view, in order to work, needs the path variable. So I used a redirect:

```
if (errors.hasErrors())
    return String.format("/appointments/%s/book", customerId);
```

but in this way the error is not passed to the `appointments/creation`.

How can I redirect to a view in case of validation errors, passing a path variable and keeping the `errors` field in the Thymeleaf rendered page?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below with `BindingResult`

```
@PostMapping("/{customerId}/book")
String bookAppointment(@PathVariable("customerId") UUID 
customerId,    @Valid AppointmentViewModel 
appointmentViewModel, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
FieldError error = new FieldError("appointment", 
"CustomerId", customerId+"has error");
bindingResult.addError(error);
        return "appointments/creation";
    }

    return "redirect:/results";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. The view cannot resolve the `customerId` variable.

Comment: I managed to pass the customerId to the controller method using `return "redirect:/appointments/{customerId}/book"`, but the errors are not passed down to the redirected method.

Comment: You want customer id in the error then add customized error in the bund results.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this:

```
@PostMapping("/{customerId}/book")
    String bookAppointment(@PathVariable("customerId") UUID customerId,
                           @ModelAttribute("appointment") @Valid AppointmentViewModel appointmentViewModel,
                           Errors errors) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "appointments/creation";
        }
        Instant appointmentDateTime = timeConverter.toInstant(appointmentViewModel.getDateTime());
        appointmentsService.book(customerId, appointmentDateTime);
        return String.format("redirect:/appointments/%s/list", customerId);
    }
```

The difference is the `@ModelAttribute("appointment")` which binds the model to the attribute named `appointment`.
This was necessary as the name of the class I was using as DTO was not `Appointment` but `AppointmentViewModel`.
If I had used `Appointment` it would have worked from the beginning.